# how to query for multiple conditions with different callback using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with mongoose for my `MongoDB`

Here's my question:
say I want to save new information from incoming request but I want to make sure that there is no duplicate information to be saved.

```
User.findOne({email : req.body.email},(err,email)=>{
    if(err) return res.send('there is some errors');
    else if (email) return res.send('this email has been used');
    else {
        User.findOne({username : req.body.username},(errR,username)=>{
            if(errR) return res.send('there is some errors');
            else if (username) return res.send('this username has been used');
            else {
                User.findOne({SID : req.body.SID},(ERR,SID)=>{
                    if(ERR) return res.send('there is some error') ; 
                    else if (SID) return res.send('this SID is used before') ; 
                    else{
                        //if we get here means that there was no duplicate information
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
 })
```

This is my approach so far, but I'm looking for a efficient way because I think this chain will be somehow messy and complicated for more entries.

Is there any simpler way for implementing this operation ?

**I think the header of the question is not appropriate for my question but any edit suggestion will be appreciated**

Comment: What do you mean by "check duplication of 5 properties"? It would be better to "show us" instead rather than talk about, since then we might understand you. Even with the two values here this does not make any sense. With a "user account" you have **one primary key** and that is most likely either the `username` or `email` depending on your sensibilities. If you think there is anything other than that which needs to be enforced "unique", then you are likely headed in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thank for your feedback, but I think There is no one-way rule for this to have one primary key necessarily. I just wanted to know whether this structure for duplication checking  is right or not for 5 fields? if not, what is the right way to do so. @NeilLunn

Comment: Please stop talking about "duplication" and actually show us what you are trying to do. We don't understand you and you don't seem to understand what is wrong about what we "think" you are doing. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50241945/edit) and "show us" so you can get an answer. That's the easiest way here.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry would you let me know how you'll handle this scenario for checking duplicate information in database ? it would be great with code example. thanks @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mongo [$or operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

```
User.findOne({
   $or: [
      {email : req.body.email},
      {username: req.body.email},
      {SID : req.body.SID}
   ]
},
(err, user)=>{
   if(err) return res.send('there is some errors');
   else if (user.email === req.body.email) return res.send('this email has been used');
   else if (user.username === req.body.username) return res.send('this username has been used');
    //..
});
```

You can also consider using [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/), but I'm not sure the error message will be so descriptive.

Comment: Thank you alex, this is what I was looking for.